# PowerPoint: edit master slide shapes from within slides

Tags: mac, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, office365, office-for-mac

I've made a master slide layout in Powerpoint, consisting of a rectangle with a textbox inside it.

I would like to adjust the rectangle so that it contains the textbox, as the text differs between slides.

See here how the text overlaps the rectangle, is it possible to 'unlock' the rectangle so that I can make it wider? With a different width on each slide?

Or would I need to make a bunch of different master slide layouts?:

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't fill the textbox with white and dispense with the rectangle altogether?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg good point, I hadnt thought of that! :)